# Calling object methods in javascript from html oninput() event

Tags: javascript, html, object, events, methods

In javascript I have a list of objects of the same class. 
Every object has the same variables and methods.
**For each object that is added to the list, an input field is added in the html code**.

Now, when the value of an input field is changed (`<input oninput=...>`)
I want to call the `inputModified()`method of the exact object in the list that was added to the list along with the input field.
How would you achieve this?

Also, if an object is removed from the list, than the html code that was added for that object is removed as well.

Is an incremental id the only way?
Also, please note that I can not use jquery or anything similar. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). It would help us help you if you include a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 1):

The best way is not to use `<input oninput=...>` at all. Use modern event handling. Then you either attach a handler that closes over the entry in the list, or you include the position in the list on the element and use a delegated `input` handler on the container these `input`s are in to figure out which entry on the list to update.

Here's an example of that first option, closing over the entry in the list:

```js
function addToDOM(entry) {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = entry.value;
    // The event handler closes over `input` and `entry`
    input.addEventListener("input", function() {
        entry.value = input.value;
    });
    return input;
}

const list = [];
const container = document.getElementById("container");
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    const entry = {
        value: `Value ${n + 1}`
    };
    container.appendChild(addToDOM(entry));
    list.push(entry);
}

// Adding another later
setTimeout(() => {
    const entry = {
        value: "Added later"
    };
    container.appendChild(addToDOM(entry));
    list.push(entry);
}, 800);

document.getElementById("btnShowAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
    list.forEach(({value}, index) => {
        console.log(`[${index}].value = ${value}`);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnShowAll" value="Show All">
<div id="container"></div>
```

Here's an example of the second option with a single delegated handler. Note, though, that if you modify the list, the index we're storing as a `data-*` attribute gets out of date:

```js
function addToDOM(entry, index) {
    const input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "text";
    input.value = entry.value;
    input.setAttribute("data-index", index);
    return input;
}

const list = [];
const container = document.getElementById("container");
container.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
    const input = e.target;
    const index = +input.getAttribute("data-index");
    list[index].value = input.value;
});
for (let n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
    const entry = {
        value: `Value ${n + 1}`
    };
    container.appendChild(addToDOM(entry, list.length));
    list.push(entry);
}

// Adding another later
setTimeout(() => {
    const entry = {
        value: "Added later"
    };
    container.appendChild(addToDOM(entry, list.length));
    list.push(entry);
}, 800);

document.getElementById("btnShowAll").addEventListener("click", function() {
    list.forEach(({value}, index) => {
        console.log(`[${index}].value = ${value}`);
    });
});
```

```html
<input type="button" id="btnShowAll" value="Show All">
<div id="container"></div>
```